# CentOS7 firewall 設定について

Tags: centos

**現状**

```
 # firewall-cmd --list-all
```

> ports: 443/tcp 80/tcp

---

**Q1.上記コマンドを打ったら、ポート番号が表示されたのですが、これは正常な状態ですか(SSHのポート番号は表示されなくても良い)？**
・[参考にしたサイト](https://qiita.com/ktkiyoshi/items/bf920b4df02d98b570e3)では(セキュリティを考慮したためか)何も表示されていなかったので、疑問に思い質問しました

**Q2.443と80は変更しなくても良い？**
・SSHのポート番号は変更したのですが、443(HTTPS)と80(HTTP)は、別に変更しなくても良いのでしょうか？
・セキュリティのリスクは異なる？？

---

**追記**
・ポート番号が表示された理由が分かりました
・OSインストール時に、コピペで下記コマンドを実行していました

```
firewall-cmd --permanent --add-port={80,443}/tcp
```

**Q3.現状「ポート」「サービス名」の両方を指定してしまっている状態ですが、これはマズいでしょうか？**
・そもそも、両者はどう使い分けるのでしょうか？

```
firewall-cmd --permanent --add-port={80,443}/tcp
firewall-cmd --permanent --zone=public --add-service=http
firewall-cmd --permanent --zone=public --add-service=https
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A1. 参考URLでは以下のコマンドを実行することで

```
# firewall-cmd --permanent --zone=public --add-service=http 
# firewall-cmd --permanent --zone=public --add-service=https
```

確認コマンド実行時、`services:`の行に`http`と`https`として**サービス名**で表示されているようです。

```
# firewall-cmd --list-all
public (default, active)
  interfaces: eth0
  sources:
  services: dhcpv6-client http https ssh
```

A2. 80(HTTP)と443(HTTPS)はウェブサーバとして公開する際のデフォルトポートなので、変更した場合にはユーザが外部からアクセスする際のURLも変更があると通知する必要があります。

参考にされたページではウェブサーバの設定手順を載せているのでHTTP/HTTPSを許可しているのだと思います。
該当のポートで何も通信をしないのであれば閉じてしまった方が安全でしょう。

---

**追記**
A3. サービス名での登録は、ポート番号よりも分かりやすくするための仕組みとして用意されているのだと思います。サービスの定義は`/usr/lib/firewalld/services/`以下にXMLファイルとして保存されているようなので、質問のように「ポート番号」と「サービス名」とで登録してしまった場合でも設定に矛盾が無ければ害は無いと思いますが、有効/無効を切り替える場合などに二度手間になりますので、気づいた段階で不要な方(ポート番号)の設定を削除しておいた方がよいかと思います。

Comment: 原因が分かったので(新たな疑問も)追記しました

Comment: 回答追記ありがとうございました。「有効/無効を切り替える場合などに二度手間になります」なるほど、アドバイス通り不要な方(ポート番号)の設定を削除しようと思いました。大変参考になりました